# Video taken on iPhone showing up as black when opened in Quicktime, but fine when opened in VLC?

Tags: video, iphone, quicktime

I took a video on my iPhone 4S upside down. I searched around the Internet and found a post stating that Apple's QuickTime Pro can losslessly rotate/flip videos. First of all, is this definitely the case? My problems would be irrelevant if there were other programs that would be able to flip my video's orientation while keeping 99.99% of the quality.

If QuickTime Pro is the only/best program to use for this purpose, why is the video portion of the file not showing up? When I play the video in QuickTime, I view a black rectangle taking up the entire resolution of the video and I am able to hear the video's audio. If I open the same video file in VLC or Windows Media Player, the video shows up fine along with the audio.

Answer (score 1):

Any video editing/converitng software can do this easily, vlc as well as media player classic aren't built for it, but should be able to flip/rotate video during playback.

EDIT: As for your second question/problem, this is not surprising, apple can make some nice stuff, but there video software and the codecs that go along with them aren't usually the best, most likely a codec problem as VLC comes with it's own codecs and far more then most media players.

Comment: Will VLC be able to vertically and horizontally flip the video and then export the new version without losing quality? Is there a VLC wiki page that would explain how to do this?

Comment: I cannot guarantee the quality as I have never had to export the video after flipping it, but yes you should be able to export it after flipping with vlc, instructions are as easy as googling "how to rotate and export video in vlc" as there many pages on how to do so on many sites including VLCs own site.

Comment: If this was the solution to your problem feel free to upvote it or mark it as the answer.